# Using PhantomJS in R (v3.6.0) on macOS High Sierra (10.13.6) for Webscraping Javascript Table Returns Partial Table

Tags: javascript, r, web-scraping, html-table, phantomjs

I'm new to programming and have no experience webscraping. I'm running R version 3.6.0 on a macOS High Sierra (10.13.6).

As part of a research project, I am attempting to scrape a table with 2,000 observations from the [Forbes website](https://www.forbes.com/global2000/list/) and save it as a data frame in R. Taking guidance from [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GayFRUUtHj4), I was able to extract the first ten rows of the 2,000 row table. I'm not sure why only the first 10 rows are being collected, and while I have looked around many blogs and tutorials, I cannot seem to find a fix to this problem.

Note: The webpage table has an ad banner in every tenth row (1-10, ad, 11-20, ad, ...). Could this be prompting PhantomJS to stop scraping the table?

Like I said, I am new to webscraping and am not too sure of the moving parts. Any insight or resources you could suggest or provide would mean a lot!

Here is the code that I'm using, which successfully extracts the first 10 rows but not the full 2,000:

```
 ## Install packages if necessary:

install.packages("rvest")
install.packages("stringr")
install.packages("plyr")
install.packages("dplyr")
install.packages("ggvis")
install.packages("knitr")

## Load them:

library("rvest")
library("stringr")
library("plyr")
library("dplyr")
library("ggvis")
library("knitr")

### At this point I downloaded and moved PhantomJS to my working directory.

## Establish connections

url <- ("https://www.forbes.com/global2000/list/")
connection <- "forbes_list.js"

## Extract content

writeLines(sprintf("var page = require('webpage').create();
                   page.open('%s', function() {
                   console.log(page.content); //page source
                   phantom.exit();
                   })", url), con = connection)

system_input <- "./phantomjs forbes_list.js>forbes_list.html"

system(system_input)

## Read in html

html <- "forbes_list.html"
pg <- read_html(html)

## Extract Table

table <- pg %>%html_nodes(xpath = '(//*[@id="the_list"])') %>% html_table()
```

I get the following result:

```
> table
[[1]]
      Rank                    Company Country/Territory    Sales
1  NA   #1                       ICBC             China $175.9 B
2  NA   #2             JPMorgan Chase     United States $132.9 B
3  NA   #3    China Construction Bank             China $150.3 B
4  NA   #4 Agricultural Bank of China             China $137.5 B
5  NA   #5            Bank of America     United States $111.9 B
6  NA   #6                      Apple     United States $261.7 B
7  NA   #7    Ping An Insurance Group             China $151.8 B
8  NA   #8              Bank of China             China $126.7 B
9  NA   #9          Royal Dutch Shell       Netherlands $382.6 B
10 NA  #10                Wells Fargo     United States $101.5 B
   Profits     Assets Market Value
1  $45.2 B $4,034.5 B     $305.1 B
2  $32.7 B $2,737.2 B     $368.5 B
3  $38.8 B $3,382.4 B       $225 B
4  $30.9 B $3,293.1 B       $197 B
5  $28.5 B $2,377.2 B     $287.3 B
6  $59.4 B   $373.7 B     $961.3 B
7  $16.3 B $1,038.3 B     $220.2 B
8  $27.5 B $3,097.6 B       $143 B
9  $23.3 B   $399.2 B     $264.9 B
10 $23.1 B $1,887.8 B     $214.7 B
```

So it works great! But not great enough ... :/

Again, any help is much appreciated!!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Your scrape is having trouble because the page is dynamically loading content as you scroll. If you search [scrape "infinite scroll"](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=scrape+infinite+scroll) or "endless scroll", you'll find some resources or at could focus your question for better answers.

Comment: Fwiw, I've found WebScraper Chrome extension easier for a quick analysis. I've used PhantomJS and CasperJS, but for more automated production use.

Comment: Unfortunately I was not able to get this to work on PhantomJS. However, thank you @ravic_ for your Chrome WebScaper recommendation. Worked like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

I have been able to get access to the first 100 rows of the table with the following code :

```
library(RSelenium)
library(XML)
library(RCurl)
shell('docker run -d -p 4445:4444 selenium/standalone-firefox')
remDr <- remoteDriver(remoteServerAddr = "localhost", port = 4445L, browserName = "firefox")
remDr$open()
remDr$navigate('https://www.forbes.com/lists/global2000/#8cc3b3e5ac04')

remDr$executeScript("scroll(0, 5000)")
remDr$executeScript("scroll(0, 15000)")
Sys.sleep(4)

remDr$screenshot(display = TRUE, useViewer = TRUE) 

page_Content <- remDr$getPageSource()[[1]]
table <- readHTMLTable(page_Content)[[1]]
table
```

Now, to got to next page, you can use the following code to get the next 100 values :

```
web_Obj_Next_Page <- remDr$findElement("xpath", "//*[@id='row-4']/div/ul/li/div/div/div[2]/div/div/ul/li[11]/a")
web_Obj_Next_Page$clickElement()                 
page_Content <- remDr$getPageSource()[[1]]
table <- readHTMLTable(page_Content)[[1]]
table
```

You can use a for loop to get all the 2000 values.